# Google Maps API v3: Handle usage Limit restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

Google maps has a limit on the API usage:
All web services    Rate limit of 10 requests per second, per web service. The Google Places API has separate usage limits.
Ref: [Google Maps API Usage Limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#js_usage_limits)

I have sending more than 10 requests to Google Maps API.
Below is a sample code that I have written using [JQuery.ui.maps](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples) :

```
 $('#map').gmap('displayDirections', {
             'origin': new google.maps.LatLng(42.645573,-71.098326),
             'destination': new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-72.298326),
             'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING },
             {suppressMarkers: true},function(success, result) {
                if ( success )
                   alert('Results found!');
             });
```

I have updated the following jquery function as per my requirements. 
I have added a sleep/delay of 1 second for each request.

```
displayDirections: function(current, directionsRequest, directionsRendererOptions, callback) {
        alert("displayDirections "+current);
        var startTime = new Date().getTime(); // get the current time
            while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 1000) {
            } // hog cpu
        var self = this;        
        var directionService = this.get('services > DirectionsService', new google.maps.DirectionsService());

        var directionRenderer =new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(directionsRendererOptions);

        directionService.route(directionsRequest, function(results, status) {
            alert("directionService Called " + current);
            var startTime = new Date().getTime(); // get the current time
            while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 1000) {
            } // hog cpu
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                directionRenderer.setDirections(results);
                directionRenderer.setMap(self.get('map'));
            } else {
                alert(status)
                directionRenderer.setMap(null);
            }
            self.get('directionRenderers').push(directionRenderer);

            callback(results, status);
        });
    }
```

But it is not working as required.
Can someone help me by showing how to work around this restriction.

Let me know in case if more details are required.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a sleep....ever hear of setTimeout?

Comment: thanks @Adam for the help. Used `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the status for 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT', and if you get this then you can delay for a few seconds, like $.delay(3000):  http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Are you exceeding the daily limits, or the 10/second limit?

Comment: I am exceeding the 10/second limit